# Downloading file with parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript app that I would like to send parameters to a server and download a pretty big pdf file based on those parameters, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.
I initially had the idea of sending a request to the server and getting a data uri back to then download it as a file to the client, but passing around a 10MB string in the response doesn't seem like a good idea.
I have also seen options of navigating to a link that simply points to the file, but since the file is generated using the data recieved from the client, I'm not sure how I would do that either.

Comment: Well, you're already doing that, sending parameters to the server and having the server generate a PDF in response. Just instead of doing that with an AJAX request, open that URL in a new window with the parameters in the query string; then the response will download as a file.

Comment: @deceze So if I send the uri of the pdf file as a response and try to open that response on the client it will automatically download the file?

Comment: You're currently making an AJAX request to `url`, and the AJAX response is the generated file, correct? Then you already have the HTTP mechanisms in place: you make an HTTP request to the server, and the server responds with a file. Your only problem is how to turn that AJAX response into a file download. For that, simply do `window.location = url` (or open a new window with that URL) instead of an AJAX request to the URL. Done.

Comment: Or I think you meant I should open the get request that will receive the file, and that will download the file automatically

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Thank you!